# Facebook API : How to get user feed or Home Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we get Facebook Home Feed, where we can see friends post/ status, using Facebook API ?

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of October 6th, 2015, this endpoint is no longer available.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/home

Graph API Reference /{user-id}/home

This endpoint returns posts a person sees in their News Feed. The posts returned by this API may not be identical to the posts a person would see on facebook.com or in Facebook's mobile apps.

As of October 6th, 2015, this endpoint is no longer available. Please consider using the /user-id/feed edge instead.

You may use /me/feed to get the user's posts :-)

Comment: It looks like you can only get the posts the user is tagged in, the posts they have posted, or the posts that other people made on that user's timeline, and not the posts that the user would see from their friends: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed